# Retrieving and displaying binary images from database laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to return the images for each row in my database through the controller

```
public function getEmotions() {    

        $emotionsList = Emotions::all();

        $images = DB::table('emotions')->select('image')->get();

        return $images;

    }
```

This returns the error Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

I have tried this as a solution

```
public function getEmotions() {    

        $emotionsList = Emotions::all();

        $images = DB::table('emotions')->select('image')->get();

        return utf8_encode($images);

    }
```

But this then returns the error Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::__toString() must return a string value

I'm a but stuck with it now, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

This data is also being passed to a Vue file where I want to display the images from. Could I add this as {{ emotion.image }}?

```
<label v-for="emotion in emotions" class="cb-container">{{ emotion.em_name }}                      
    <input name="emotions[]" type="checkbox" :value="emotion.id">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $images = DB::table('emotions')->select('image')**->get()**;

The `get()` method provided by Laravel **return an instance of** `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class.

By definition an

> Illuminate\Support\Collection class provides a fluent, convenient
>   wrapper for working with **arrays** of data.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections)

The point is: you need to loop through your $images var and `utf8_encode` each row separately like

```
foreach($images as $image) {
 ...
}
```

**Edit**

You may use

```
public function getEmotions() {    

   $emotionsList = Emotions::all();

   foreach($emotionsList as $emotion) {
      $emotion->image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $emotion->image);
   }

   return $emotionsList;
}
```

**Usage**

```
... v-for="emotion in emotions" ...
      <img src="$emotion->image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return a response:

```
return response($images->toArray());
```

Or if you want it encoded in json:

```
return response()->json($images);
```